# What did Swami Vivekananda mean when he said "God spoke in Sanskrit"?

Tags: gods, sanskrit, language, vivekananda

I read this quote by *Swami Vivekananda*:

> God spoke once. He spoke in Sanskrit, and that is the divine language.

What did he mean by this?

Comment: @AmitSaxena: Could you please share the link where he spoke this statement?

Comment: Could it be a reference to the Bhagvad Geeta?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal, he meant the Vedas

Answer (score 3):

It is from the The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda[/Volume 3.](https://archive.org/stream/SWAMIVIVEKANANDACOMPLETEWORKSVol3/SWAMI-VIVEKANANDA-COMPLETE-WORKS-Vol-3#page/n425/mode/2up/search/God+spoke+once).

While quoting the statement from Abrahamic Text "In the beginning was the Word and the Word was with God ", Swami said that the **Word is the Vedas, and Sanskrit is the language of God. God spoke once. He spoke in Sanskrit**.

The following is the extract.

> There was already in India a vast religion with an organised scripture
>   — the Vedas; and these Vedas existed as a mass of literature and not a
>   book — just as you find the Old Testament, the Bible. Now, the Bible
>   is a mass of literature of different ages; different persons are the
>   writers, and so on. It is a collection.
>
> Now, the Vedas are a vast collection. I do not know whether, if the
>   texts were all found — nobody has found all the texts, nobody even in
>   India has seen all the books — if all the books were known, this room
>   would contain them. It is a huge mass of literature, carried down from
>   generation to generation from God, who gave the scriptures. And the
>   idea about the scriptures in India became tremendously orthodox.
>
> You complain of your orthodoxies in book-worship. If you get the
>   Hindus' idea, where will you be? **The Hindus think the Vedas are the
>   direct knowledge of God**, that God has created the whole universe in
>   and through the Vedas, and that the whole universe exists because it
>   is in the Vedas. The cow exists outside because the word "cow" is in
>   the Vedas; man exists outside because of the word in the Vedas.
>
> Here you see the beginning of that theory which later on Christians
>   developed and expressed in the text: ***"In the beginning was the Word
>   and the Word was with God*** " ***It is the old, ancient theory of
>   India***. Upon that is based the whole idea of the scriptures. And
>   mind, every word is the power of God. The word is only the external
>   manifestation on the material plane.
>
> So, all this manifestation is just the manifestation on the material
>   plane; ***and the Word is the Vedas, and Sanskrit is the language of
>   God. God spoke once. He spoke in Sanskrit,*** and that is the
>   ***divine language***. Every other language, they consider, is no more than the braying of animals; and to denote that they call every other
>   nation that does not speak Sanskrit [Mlechchhas], the same word as the
>   barbarians of the Greeks. They are braying, not talking, and Sanskrit
>   is the divine language.